# Pagination styling won't work

Tags: html, css

I think it is a very stupid question, but i can't figure it out!
I want to make a pagination, and style it with css.

this is my css:

```
.pagination {
    height:14px;
    width:auto;
    float:right;
}
.first {
    width:14px;
    height:14px;
    background:url('../images/first.png');
    margin:0 3px;
}
.last {
    width:14px;
    height:14px;
    background:url('../images/last.png');
    margin:3px;
}
.next {
    width:7px;
    height:14px;
    background:url('../images/next.png');
    margin:3px;
}
.previous {
    width:7px;
    height:14px;
    background:url('../images/previous.png');
    margin:3px;
}
```

and the HTML is this:

```
<div class="pagination">
                <a href="#" class="first"></a>
                <a href="#" class="previous"></a>
                <a href="#" class="next"></a>
                <a href="#" class="last"></a>
            </div>
```

But there is nothing to see at the website.

Someone that can help ?
Thx

Comment: Check whether the path to images are correct

Comment: Can you provide the link? So that we can check the image is loading or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `display: inline-block;` to your styles for each of the `<a />` tags then that should work.

```
a{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And make sure that the path to the image is correct.